# How to write two arrays as a 2-channel WAV file?

Tags: c, wav

I'm working with C and I have two dynamic arrays that I would like to write to a stereo WAV file (16bit 96000hz).

What would be the best way to do this?

```
int* channel1 = malloc(sizeof(int)*4800);
int* channel2 = malloc(sizeof(int)*4800);

// write to 16bit WAV @ 96kHz??
```

Comment: Either use a library which someone else has written to read/write WAV, or lookup the WAV file format, and write the binary data yourself using a FILE in write binary mode. The format for WAV is pretty simple. There's some references online, I'll find you the one I used years ago if it still exists.

Comment: A quick search and I haven't been able to find the reference I previously used. It looks like python provides a very simple library, so if you know python / wanted to learn you could try that. Otherwise you just need to find a spec which tells you how to write the headers and then how to write the data. The data is easy, it's (usually) going to be 16 bit signed integer PCM, unless you change it using the data in the header. (Float is also supported, at least as 32 bit, maybe also 64.)

Comment: The last time I had to do this I just wrote the raw samples to a file then used `ffmpeg` to convert to WAV. Saved a lot of headache, but may not be appropriate for all projects.

Comment: One thing you will need to be aware of is that you need to interleave your samples. ie: Left and right channels have to be interleaved together so that when a file is read or written, samples appear in a time-ordered way. It's fine to have two independent buffers for left and right but at some point you need to zip them up before reading/writing.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I've used pysoundfile with python before for doing this and am aware of the interleaving for a stereo file. Are you implying I could merge a python code with the C? or just use python entirely? Python worked in the past but was very slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a method that works. The data is written to a raw file in c and then that is read and converted to WAV in python using pysoundfile.

C code

- I'm using int16_t to ensure each value is 2 bytes. Not sure if this is even necessary but it works so I'm going to leave it alone.

```
// Writes data to raw file
    FILE *fp = fopen("video_signal.R", "w");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Output file couldn't be opened!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int16_t byte;
    for (int i = 0; i < (4800*frame_count); i++)
    {
        byte = channel1[i];
        fwrite(&byte, 2, 1, fp);
        byte = channel2[i];
        fwrite(&byte, 2, 1, fp);
    }

    fclose(fp);
```

Python code

```
with open("video_signal.R", 'rb') as f:
    size = int(os.path.getsize("video_signal.R") / 2)
    for _ in range(0, size, 1):
        ch1 = int.from_bytes(f.read(2), byteorder='little')
        ch2 = int.from_bytes(f.read(2), byteorder='little')
        output.append([ch1, ch2])

for i in range(0, len(output), 1):
    [ch1, ch2] = output[i]
    ch1 -= sync_level
    ch2 -= sync_level
    if ch1 > sync_level:
        ch1 = sync_level
    elif ch1 < 0 - sync_level:
        ch1 = 0 - sync_level
    if ch2 > sync_level:
        ch2 = sync_level
    elif ch2 < 0 - sync_level:
        ch2 = 0 - sync_level
    ch1 = ch1 / sync_level
    ch2 = ch2 / sync_level
    output[i] = [ch1, ch2]

sf.write("video_signal.wav", output, 96000, subtype="PCM_16");
os.remove("video_signal.R");
```

Answer (score 1):

I pulled this pretty old code out of a samba archive which I still have access to.

You should be aware that this is really, really old code and it's not at all well written. The fact I have a wav file in the same project directory tells me that at some point I managed to get this to compile and work.

It's not great, but might point you in the right direction.

Btw, there's some C++ stuff in here but you can probably fairly easily remove that and convert it to pure C if that is your intention.

The date on this says 2016, but that's the date it was written to the samba server. This is probably way older than that, from when I first started learning C++.

A few points to note:

- There are two headers/sections in the file, one is marked `'data'`, the other is marked `'riff'`.
- Basically you write one header and then write the rest of the data
- You should cross check this with a reference for the wav file format, to ensure everything is correct

I will keep looking around for you to see if I can find a better example.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>


#ifndef __WAVWRITER__HPP__
#define __WAVWRITER__HPP__


class WaveWriter
{


    /// Constructor and Destructor
public:
    WaveWriter();
    ~WaveWriter();
    WaveWriter(const WaveWriter& clone);
    const WaveWriter& operator=(const WaveWriter& clone);


    /// Methods
public:
    void WriteHead(std::string filename, int bytestreamsize, int channels, int samplerate);

    /// Data
private:
    unsigned char[] RIFF_HEAD = char[] {'R', 'I', 'F', 'F'};
    unsigned char[] FORMAT_WAVE = char[] {'W', 'A', 'V', 'E'};
    unsigned char[] FORMAT_TAG = char[] {'f', 'm', 't', ' '};
    unsigned char[] AUDIO_FORMAT = char[] {0x01, 0x00};
    unsigned char[] SUBCHUNK_ID = char[] {'d', 'a', 't', 'a'};
    int BYTES_PER_SAMPLE = 2;

    std::ofstream output_stream;
};


#endif




#include "wavwriter.hpp"

WaveWriter::WaveWriter()
{
}

WaveWriter::~WaveWriter()
{
}


void WaveWriter::WriteHead(std::string filename, int bytestreamsize, int channels, int samplerate)
{

    int BYTE_RATE = samplerate * channels * BYTES_PER_SAMPLE;
    int BLOCK_ALIGN = channels * BYTES_PER_SAMPLE;

    output_stream.open(filename);

    output_stream.write(RIFF_HEAD, 4);
    unsigned char[] total_file_size = char[] {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0};
    output_stream.write(total_file_size);
    output_stream.write(FORMAT_WAVE, 4);
    output_stream.write(FORMAT_TAG, 4);
    unsigned char[] sub_chunk_size = char[] {0x0, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0};
    output_stream.write(sub_chunk_size, 4);
    output_stream.write(AUDIO_FORMAT, 2);
    unsigned char[] channel_count = char[] {0x0, 0x2};
    output_stream.write(channel_count, 2);
    unsigned char[] sample_rate = char[] {0xa, 0xc, 0x4, 0x4};
    output_stream.write(sample_rate, 4);
    unsigned char[] byte_rate = char[] {0x1, 0x5, 0x8, 0x8, 0x8, 0x0};
    output_stream.write(byte_rate, 4);

}
```

---

Here's a second example. Again, generally speaking this is very bad code because apparently I inherited from a standard libary component before knowing this shouldn't be done.

This one is maybe a bit easier to understand.

Here's how it works:

- When the class is initialized it opens an output stream with the specified filename
- It writes the common header information, writing zeros into the fields which are not known yet, such as the data length
- You continually call send data to push data to the output stream in a buffered manner
- When the destructor is called, the class automatically writes any remaning data to the file, rewinds the file to the beginning, and then writes over the previously zero fields with the final length information now it is known

In some ways what I did here was quite clever, but this isn't at all what you would expect to see in a typical C++ API.

```
#ifndef WAVFSTREAM_HPP
#define WAVFSTREAM_HPP

class wavofstream : protected std::ofstream
{

public:

    wavofstream(const char* const filename)
        : std::ofstream(filename)
        //, m_buffer(m_buffer_size)
        , m_buffer_ix{0}
        , m_datasize{0}
    {
        std::cout << "Buffer length: " << m_buffer_size << std::endl;
        m_buffer.resize(m_buffer_size);

        // write initial header here

        if(is_open())
        {
            // RIFF
            put('R');
            put('I');
            put('F');
            put('F');

            // Chunksize
            // Entire filesize - 8 bytes
            // or
            // 4 + 8 + subchunk1size + 8 + subchunk2size
            put(0);
            put(0);
            put(0);
            put(0);

            // WAVE
            put('W');
            put('A');
            put('V');
            put('E');

            // FMT<space>
            put('f');
            put('m');
            put('t');
            put(' ');

            // Subchunk Size
            // Size of the remaining data in this subchunk following from this point
            // (there are 16 bytes)
            put(16);
            put(0);
            put(0);
            put(0);

            // PCM
            put(1);
            put(0);

            // Channels
            put(2);
            put(0);

            // Sample Rate (44100)
            put(0x44);
            put(0xAC);
            put(0x00);
            put(0x00);

            // Byte Rate
            put(0x10);
            put(0xB1);
            put(0x02);
            put(0x00);

            // Block Align
            put(4);
            put(0);

            // Bits Per Sample
            put(16);
            put(0);

            // Data
            put('d');
            put('a');
            put('t');
            put('a');

            // Data subchunk size (bytes)
            // 4 * num samples
            put(0);
            put(0);
            put(0);
            put(0);

        }
    }

    ~wavofstream()
    {
        // write remaining buffer content
        write((const char*)&m_buffer[0], m_buffer_ix);

        // write filesize and datasize here (finalize header)

        seekp(4, std::ios::beg);

        uint32_t file_length = 36 + m_datasize;

        put((file_length & 0x000000FF) >> 0);
        put((file_length & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
        put((file_length & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
        put((file_length & 0xFF000000) >> 24);

        seekp(40, std::ios::beg);

        uint32_t data_length = m_datasize;
        std::cout << data_length << std::endl;

        put((data_length & 0x000000FF) >> 0);
        put((data_length & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
        put((data_length & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
        put((data_length & 0xFF000000) >> 24);
    }

    void senddata(const unsigned char* const data, uint32_t length)
    {
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < length; ++ i)
        {
            m_buffer[m_buffer_ix] = data[i];
            ++ m_buffer_ix;
            if(m_buffer_ix == m_buffer.size())
            {
                write((const char*)&m_buffer[0], m_buffer.size());
                m_buffer_ix = 0;
            }
            //put(data[i]);
        }

        m_datasize += length;
    }


protected:

    uint32_t m_datasize;
    std::vector<unsigned char> m_buffer;
    const uint64_t m_buffer_size = 512 * 1024;
    uint64_t m_buffer_ix;
};


#endif
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't really understand what's going on there. I haven't learned much c++ so any c++ code is confusing to me at best. I understand the concept from your explanation but cannot decipher the code enough to implement.

Comment: @JakeA Point me to which parts are completely inpenetrable to you and I'll add some explanation.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I found a solution that works. Thanks though!